# Displaying selected dropdown option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Hi this is my first question,

first of all;

I have created a dropdown in html, with values inside,
I would like to 'echo' or 'display' the option I have 'SELECTED' or 'CLICKED' from the dropdown e.g, I click/select 'foo' in the dropdown, I now see text on the screen 'foo' being echo'd/displayed.

I wish to do this without refreshing the page etc.. I understand I will be using php/html and possible javascript/jquery.

Can somebody write a basic script/demo of that^
Much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? The context is too broad to be productive for SO.

Comment: We're not here to write scripts and demos for you upon request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple task and you shouldn't need php or jquery =)

Here's a quick solution that may work for you:

**HTML**:

```
<select>
    <option value="foo">foo</option>
    <option value="bar">bar</option>
</select>    

<div></div>
```

**JS**:

```
var select = document.querySelector("select");
var div = document.querySelector("div");

select.onchange = function(e){
    alert(this.value);
    div.innerText = this.value;
};
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/N5sqJ/)

Comment: Why would you reward such a lazy question with an answer?

Comment: @Sparky - There are no bad/lazy/stupid questions. I've answered the question because it was asked and I'm on here to help, regardless of how simple it may seem.

Comment: Nobody said anything about stupid.   Howver, "gimme the code!" type questions are very lazy and usually bad.  (Hover over the down-vote arrow for a list of valid reasons the question might be considered "bad".  Lack of research/effort is one.)

Comment: Agreed, which is why I've voted to close it as well. However, having an answer here may *hopefully* deter similar questions =)

Answer (score 0):

Well there are many ways to do it. A simple way to do it would be to use the jqwery change method on the dropdown. You might do the following.

foo
  ...
  ...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#choose").change(function () {
      var val=$("#choose").val();
      $("#out").html(val);
     });
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: None of your replies work, I need it to, as soon as I select the option 'foo' it displays 'foo' on the page